# Invalid Account Address in transfer ETH from one account to another

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, truffle, ganache

I have this node js code to transfer an amount from accounts 1 to 2:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const contract = require('truffle-contract');
const TransferContract = contract(require('./build/contracts/Transfer.json'));

async function transferFunds(from, to, amount) {
  // Set up a Web3 provider, e.g. using Ganache or Infura
  const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545');
  TransferContract.setProvider(provider);

  // Get an instance of the contract deployed at the specified address
  const instance = await TransferContract.deployed();

  // Call the transfer() function on the contract instance
  await instance.transfer(to, amount, { from: from });
}

// Call the transferFunds function with the desired parameters
transferFunds('0xDD6889bcc75510f66566d9f7Ea9C814a5C6043d8', '0xB197d9415Ed9A7ee55d35cAC889C99243c486976', 100);
```

When I run the code I see this error:

> var error = new Error(message);
>
> Error: invalid address (arg="account2", coderType="address",
> value=100)
>
> reason: 'invalid address',
> code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
> arg:  'account2',
> coderType: 'address',
> value: 100

Also, my solidity code is this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Transfer {
    function transfer(address payable account1, address payable account2, uint amount) public {
        require(address(this).balance >= amount * 2, "Insufficient funds in contract");
        account1.transfer(amount);
        account2.transfer(amount);
    }
}
```

could someone let me know what the issue is?

for more info, I test it in the Truffle and Ganache networks and both accounts have enough credit and are true addresses in the network.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, in solidity the order of input was different, so I change the orders in the js script too.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const contract = require('truffle-contract');
const TransferContract = contract(require('./build/contracts/Transfer.json'));

async function transferFunds(from, to, amount) {
  // Set up a Web3 provider, e.g. using Ganache or Infura
  const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545');
  TransferContract.setProvider(provider);

  // Get an instance of the contract deployed at the specified address
  const instance = await TransferContract.deployed();

  // Call the transfer() function on the contract instance
  await instance.transfer(from, to, amount, { from: from });
}

// Call the transferFunds function with the desired parameters
transferFunds('0xDD6889bcc75510f66566d9f7Ea9C814a5C6043d8', '0xB197d9415Ed9A7ee55d35cAC889C99243c486976', 50);
```